# Unit circle cannot be well ordered?

Tags: general-topology

This showed up while reviewing for an analysis qualifier. I thought any non empty set has a well ordering through the Axiom of Choice. Clearly I am not understanding how making the order be compatible with the topology changes things, so any help on this would be appreciated!

---

QUESTION: An ordering on a topological space is an order compatible with the topology if when $x<y$, there are distinct neighborhoods $A$ of $x$ and $B$ of $y$ such that for all $z\in A$ one has $z<y$ and for all $w\in B$ one has $x<w$.

(a) Show that the unit circle cannot be well ordered. (Hint: One proof follows the lines of the intermediate value theorem.)

(b) Show that you cannot find a well ordering of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is compatible with the Euclidean distance in the plane.

Comment: This is not as much a question about the axiom of choice, as it is a question about order topologies. The unit circle can be well-ordered if we assume the axiom of choice, the question is to show that its topology is not induced by any well-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Pick $x$ as the minimal element, and $y$ its successor. What is $A$ from the definition? Why does this finishes the proof?

Comment: It appears to me that your hint is intended to prove that topologies on the unit circle and $\mathbb R^2$ cannot be induced by an order topology? But the question is about finding an ordering that is "compatible" with those topologies, which seems to be different.

Comment: Dustan, the question is to show that *there is no compatible* well-ordering.

Comment: There is a definition given in the question, which is certainly not a familiar definition to me, so it's just not clear to me whether you're using that definition.

Comment: Dustan, do you see why the definition in the question is equivalent to saying that the topology is generated by the open intervals of the linear order?

Comment: No, that's not clear to me at all. Everything in $A$ must be less than $y$ and everything in $B$ must be greater than $x$, but, for example, the condition does not require that everything in $A$ be less than everything in $B$.

Comment: @Dustan:  Draw this picture:  Pick a point on the unit circle.  Draw a neighborhood about it.  Go $\2pi - \epsilon$ radians, counter clockwise.  Where is that new point?  What does that mean for your definition?

Comment: Okay, as a first step, do you see why this implies that all the open intervals are open in the topology?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If that were the case, then there would be a much more trivial solution to this problem utilizing the fact that neither topologies have singleton open sets.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is a simpler solution. One doesn't even need "all" the intervals. It sufficient to point out a single finite neighborhood.

Comment: I understand the solution given in your edit now. I don't understand how you get that this compatibility condition implies the topology is induced by the order, but I guess that's now a separate issue.

Comment: @Dustan: I might be wrong about that, now that I think about it some more. It just seems very weird to say that an order is compatible with a topology is not the same as requiring that it induces it; this would be like saying that a topology is a metric topology if there is some metric which satisfies some condition, but not necessarily induces the topology. Weird.

Comment: I know. I have figured out a proof that intervals are open though; I don't have any reason to believe that you're wrong yet. It just seemed weird to me to give such a convoluted definition, unless it was properly different from the obvious condition that the topology be induced by the order.

Comment: @Dustan: Isn't this question utterly trivial if we use the definition that the topology is induced by the order? I think it is. Here you at least have to work a little bit, or try some things before you can find an easy way out.

Comment: yeah, that's fair, I suppose.

Comment: Actually, the condition seems to be simply that the topology be at least as fine as the order topology. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: For the comment record, this answer solves the original question as well; if $x$ is minimal and $y$ is its successor then we would have to have $A = \{x\}$.